If a ring $R$ decomposes as $_R R \simeq P_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n$, can any simple $R$-module be isomorphic to a quotient of some $P_i$?
If $R$ is a left Artin ring with unity and with an arbitrary decomposition of the regular module $_R R \simeq P_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n$, then we can conclude that any simple module over $R$ must be isomorphic to a quotient module of some $P_i$.
Since $R$ is left Artin, $R/\text{rad}(R)$ is semisimple, and any simple module $S$ over $R$ is a direct summand of $R/\text{rad}(R)$ through a split surjection $R/\text{rad}(R) \twoheadrightarrow S$. Because
$$R/\text{rad}(R) \simeq (P_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n)/\text{rad}(P_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n) \simeq P_1/\text{rad}(P_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n/\text{rad}(P_n),$$
$S$ is a direct summand of some $P_i/\text{rad}(P_i)$.
Based on the above analysis, we actually only need to assume $R/\text{rad}(R)$ is semisimple. That is, if $R/\text{rad}(R)$ is semisimple and with an arbitrary decomposition of the regular module $_R R \simeq P_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n$, then we can conclude that any simple module over $R$ must be isomorphic to a quotient module of some $P_i$.
Now the question arises: if a ring $R$ with unity such that $R/\text{rad}(R)$ is not semisimple and with an arbitrary decomposition of the regular module $_R R \simeq P_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n$, can we conclude that any simple module over $R$ must be isomorphic to a quotient module of some $P_i$?

I suddenly figured it out, the answer is yes.
If $S$ is a simple module over $R$ and the regular module $R$ has a decomposition $_R R \simeq P_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n$, then any simple module over $R$ must be isomorphic to a quotient module of some $P_i$.
Since there is a non-zero map $$0 \neq f = (f_1, \ldots, f_n): R \simeq P_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n \longrightarrow S,$$ we can conclude that $f_i \neq 0$ for some $i$. Thus, we have $$0 \neq f_i : P_i \to S.$$
Since $S$ is simple, $f_i$ must be a surjection. Therefore, we get $$P_i / \ker(f_i) \simeq S.$$
